# Can't open downloaded file from Browser Stack

Tags: browserstack

I can't open downloaded file from `Browser Stack` using `Safari`.  How do I copy file from `Browser Stack` using `Safari` to local or shared folder?

Comment: @Niels can you share the code..

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be documented online currently, I would [contact support](https://www.browserstack.com/contact?ref=help) and ask them.

I came up with a work around, but feels like a bit of hassle:

- Download the file in the tests
- Browse to a file upload site your test can access, for example AWS S3, Google Drive, etc.
- Upload the file again
- Download the file with from the upload service in your test-code via a http-call
- Verify the file